# ListGrid put focus in the FilterEditor

Tags: smartgwt

I have a ListGrid defined like this:

```
ListGrid lgrid = new ListGrid();
ListGridField first  = new ListGridField("first",first");
ListGridField second = new ListGridField("second ",second ");
lgrid.setFields(first, second);
lgrid.setShowFilterEditor(true);
```

¿How can i put the keyboard focus in the first filter editor field after i call **show()** in the layout?

Thxs in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what your use case is (which would be useful to provide a more focused answer), the solution you posted might not be what you really need, because if you scroll on your ListGrid, it could trigger a new data fetch (if there are more records to show), and move the cursor to the filter editor as a result (if your user is editing some records at that point, the cursor moving to the filter row is not what she would want to happen!!).

In such a case, you probably just want to call `grid.focusInFilterEditor("fieldToFocus")` after the listGrid.show() statement or in the ClickHandler of some button you use to fetch the data, etc.

Anyway, you don't need the Timer either. This works:

```
listGrid.addDataArrivedHandler(new DataArrivedHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onDataArrived(DataArrivedEvent event) {
        grid.focusInFilterEditor("fieldToFocus");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution, its **focusInFilterEditor**, this is an example to set the focus after the data arrived to the grid:

```
   // Put the focus on the first listGrid field when is loaded    
    listGrid.addDataArrivedHandler(new DataArrivedHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onDataArrived(DataArrivedEvent event) {
                Timer t = new Timer() {
                    public void run() {     
                        if(listGrid.getFilterEditorCriteria() == null){
                            listGrid.focusInFilterEditor("fieldToFocus");
                        }
                    }
                };
                t.schedule(600);
        }
    });
```